# Constraining the metric on the boundary of space-time to get rid of unwanted equation of motion

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, boundary-conditions, action, boundary-terms

I've posted [this question on maths.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4446474/what-boundary-conditions-should-i-impose-in-this-situation) discussing the action I'm working with, which is (in Dirichlet boundary conditions) just the effective action of a minimally coupled free massive scalar field in Euclidean space-time:
\begin{align}
S=\ln \det(-\Delta_4+m^2) =& \frac{1}{16\pi^2}\int_\mathcal{M} d^4x \sqrt{g} \left[\frac{1}{2}m^4 -\frac{1}{6}m^2 R +\frac{1}{72} R^2+\frac{1}{120}C^2\right]
\\
&+B_R+B_{R^2}+B_{C^2}-\frac{1}{180}\chi(\mathcal{M})
\\
&+\frac{1}{16\pi^2}\int_{\partial \mathcal{M}}d^3x \sqrt{\gamma} \left[ \frac{1}{36}KR+\frac{2}{45}KR_{\textbf{n} \textbf{n}}-\frac{1}{90}K^{\mu \nu}R_{\textbf{n}\mu \textbf{n}\nu} \right.
\\
&+\left.\frac{1}{15}K^{\mu \nu}R_{\mu \nu}+\frac{4}{315}K^3-\frac{2}{35}KK_{\mu \nu}K^{\mu \nu}+\frac{26}{945}K^\alpha_\beta K^\beta_\gamma K^\gamma_\alpha\right]. \tag{1}
\end{align}
Where $R$ is the Ricci scalar, $C^2$ the Weyl quadratic term, $B_X$ are the boundary terms associated with the $X$ terms, $\chi(\mathcal{M})$ is the Euler characteristic of the manifold $\mathcal{M}$ with boundary $\partial \mathcal{M}$, $\gamma_{\mu \nu}$ is the induced metric, $K_{\mu \nu}$ is the extrinsic curvature, and $R_{\textbf{n} \textbf{n}}=n^\mu n^\nu R_{\mu \nu}$ for $n^\mu$ the unit normal vector to the boundary.  When I take the variational with respect to the bulk metric, upon imposing $\delta g_{\mu \nu}|_{\partial \mathcal{M}}=0$ and $\delta n^\mu|_{\partial \mathcal{M}}=0$, I find two equations of motion,
\begin{align}
0=&\lambda g_{\mu \nu}+\sigma G_{\mu \nu}-H_{\mu \nu},\tag{2}
\\
0\stackrel{\partial \mathcal{M}}{=}&n^\alpha A_{\mu \nu}.\tag{3}
\end{align}
With $H$ depending on the fourth derivatives of the metric, $\lambda$ and $\sigma$ are two constants expressed with $m^2$, and $A_{\mu \nu}$ is a tensor constructed from the induced metric, the extrinsic curvature, and the intrinsic curvature.

My guess is that one should get rid of $(3)$ because I have never seen anywhere an equation on the boundary, and I think the problem is then ill-defined. But changing the Dirichlet boundary condition to Robin means that I have a scalar field that doesn't vanish on the boundary, which can be like a bubble in space, evolving in time (so not a boundary at infinity), and so it seems physically fishy. There exist mixed boundary conditions but there's also the same kind of problem.

So, my last resort seems to impose a constraint on the metric on the boundary that affects $n$ such that $(3)$ vanishes on the boundary. That is to say, imposing $g_{\mu \nu}\mathfrak{n}^\mu \mathfrak{n}^\nu|_N \stackrel{N\rightarrow \partial \mathcal{M}}{\longrightarrow}+\infty$ for $\mathfrak{n}$ such that $n^\mu = \sqrt{g_{\alpha \beta}\mathfrak{n}^\alpha \mathfrak{n}^\beta}^{-1}\times\mathfrak{n}^\mu$. Typically, $\mathfrak{n}$ can be the normal to the boundary embedded into a space-time with no boundary. Such construction seems to imply that physically, the boundary is at an infinite distance from the exterior referential. Nevertheless, I don't know what it means without knowing the behavior of $g_{00}$ on the boundary...

Since $g_{\mu \nu}\mathfrak{n}^\mu \mathfrak{n}^\nu$ diverges on the boundary, then $n^\mu=0$ on it. And so $(3)$ vanishes provided that $A$ does not diverges faster near the same boundary.

My question is, is such construction, such constraint reasonable? It helps to bypass a possible change in boundary conditions (that may be physically unacceptable), but what can we tell for the regular Einstein-Hilbert action with the Gibbons-Hawking-York term? The variation of the latter seems to vanish also, and then it is useless. Maybe my constraint is something one must impose with quadratic gravity with boundaries and not with Einstein's gravity, I don't know (that's why I'm asking)...